# What does "circle through" do with its argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

The tikz library `through` can be used to draw a circle from a center coordinate A through another coordinate B like so:

`\node [draw] at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};`

When attempting to specify the coordinate to go through directly, i.e. without a named through coordinate

`\node [draw] at (A) [circle through=(2,2)] {};`

and compiling my document with pdflatex not only does that not work it also doesn't return and so gives no error message.

**What does `circle through` do with its argument and is there a way to prevent endless compiling and come to some error message without rewriting a tikz library?**

The way that works is to specify the coordinate in curly brackets

`\node [draw] at (A) [circle through={(2,2)}] {};`

I'm guessing `through` wasn't able to correctly retrieve its argument the other way.

Note that the [pgfmanual 2.10](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)
doesn't speak to that issue. The call is described as `/tikz/circle through=<coordinate>` (p. 474) and whenever it is used in examples named nodes are used.

I'm using TeXstudio 2.3 which runs

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test-tikzcirclethrough".tex`

Here is a test document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);
% Works
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through={(B)}] {};
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through=(B)] {};
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through={(2,2)}] {};
% Doesn't work
\node [draw] at (A) [circle through=(2,2)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because commas separate keys, so `circle through=(2,2)` is split into `circle through=(2` and `2)` before TikZ starts figuring out what the key means.  Thus the argument to `circle through` is just `(2` and that doesn't make a lot of sense.  Putting the coordinate in braces protects the comma from the key splitter, preserving it so that it is still there when TikZ starts looking for a coordinate.

Comment: What @AndrewStacey wrote is correct. This has nothing to do with `through` or `circle through`. You neither can re-write the library. This is the core of the underlying PGFkeys system (and it is the same way with every other key=value system). `circle through={(2,2)}` is the only correct way to use that option with that value. In various other situations you also need to enclose `= `, `:`, `)` or `]`.

Comment: For explanations, look at `\pgfkeys`, p. 484 of pgfmanual (v2.10)

Comment: Extract from pgfmanual: "_Especially putting the value in curly braces needs to be done quite often, namely whenever
the value contains an equal-sign or a comma._"

Comment: I looked up other cases where the expression `<coordinate>` was used and came to the conclusion that `(2,2)` is a valid instance of the expression. So `/tikz/circle through=<coordinate>` should mean that I don't need to use curly brackets. I'm guessing the pgfmanual source would show `{\langle coordinate\rangle}` instead of `\{\langle coordinate\rangle\}`. @PaulGaborit: How did you make the connection from `through` to `pgfkeys`?

Comment: @valid <coordinate> is in fact a placeholder for an expression such as `(name)` or `(value1, value2)` or `(value1:value2)` (polar coordinates) or a lot of other variants. But **_if_** the particular instance of the coordinate you use contains a comma, **_and_** it is used as a value for a key, then the whole coordinate has to be "protected" by curly braces, because of the way in which keys are parsed. The parser which interprets keys and assigns values is implemented in `pgfkeys`, hence the remark by PaulGaborit.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Please make that an answer

Comment: @valid: Another extract from section 2.19 Transformations: *"The most useful transformations are xshift and yshift for shifting, shift for shifting to a given point
as in shift={(1,0)} or shift={+(0,0)} (the braces are necessary so that T E X does not mistake the comma
for separating options), ..."*. You'll also find this construction on manual's cover.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Summarising the comments)

The problem here is that the string `circle through=(2,2)` is processed through the `pgfkeys` mechanism.  This uses commas to separate items and this splitting is done first of all before the individual keys are processed.  (In this respect, it differs a little from what might be deemed usual TeX behaviour which is "greedy" and would start processing from the left only splitting off the next key when it is done with the current one.)

So `circle through=(2,2)` gets split into `circle through=(2` and `2)`, neither of which is going to work.  The first is a valid key but its argument doesn't match what it is expecting, and the second is not even a valid key.

To get round this, we need to protect the comma in `(2,2)` so that it doesn't get mistaken for a separator.  The method of doing so in `pgfkeys` is to ensure that it is inside a TeX group.  That is to say, it is in braces.  So `circle through={(2,2)}` is the right way to do this.

(Incidentally, this is a problem encountered by any system that has special characters.  When one wants to use a literal character, one has to ensure that it is not interpreted as a special character.  We see this in TeX, just search on this site, but also with escape characters in other programming languages and - relevant for this situation - in the CSV spreadsheet format.)